# Is it bad practice to abstract out separate api routes for embedded documents in a mongodb collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose, restful-architecture

I am using node.js, express and mongodb with mongoose to build out a ReSTful api. I have 2 questions regarding ReSTful best practice in conjunction with mongodb:

1. I have 2 collections: Chapters and Pages. The Chapters collection contains an embedded array of section documents. The (simplified) schema is as follows:

```js
var sectionSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  pages: { type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], ref: 'Page' }
});

var chapterSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  sections: [sectionSchema]
});
```

The contents of each section are irrelevant for now. My question is, would it make sense in my scenario to create a controller or group of routes for getting/updating an individual section element. My intuition is that I would be breaking some kind of ReSTful api best practice,
[but perhaps not](http://apigee.com/about/blog/technology/restful-api-design-nouns-are-good-verbs-are-bad). Data access in my case would frequently need to get and update individual section elements from the sections array in the chapters collection.

2. Following on from my first question, as mentioned above, I have a 'pages' collection. If I build out routes for sections I want to make use of mongooses pseudo joins (or perhaps mongos $lookup) to return a single section element with the pages referenced its pages array. Would it make my api somehow less ReSTful considering I am accessing multiple collections. For reference the pages schema is as follows:

```js
var pageSchema = new Schema({
  chapterId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
  name: { type: String },
  text: { type: String }
});
```

Of I can accomplish all this with two controllers (Chapters and Pages) and no joins and simply fetch the referenced resources with multiple calls from the client side, but that requires more on the part of the api consumer, more requests over the wire and possibly more database hits.

In case you're wondering why I have a chapterId in each page document it's because a page belongs to a chapter and is unassigned before it is shoved somewhere into a section's array of pages. It's also a quick and easy way to get all the pages belonging to a chapter without having to query 2 collections. Feel free to comment on this aspect of my design too. Pages also require their own collection because 1. individual pages are accessed frequently and 2. pages could potentially get rather large and cumbersome.

Mostly I am using this project as an introduction into the node.js/mongodb world and web programming in general. Thanks in advance!